# How to specify information from the table being inserted on PostgreSQL upsert?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to insert values from a temporary table (`NewThings`) with columns `Thing` and `Counts` into my main table (`MyThings`) with columns `Thing` and `Count`. If a thing does not exist in the main table I want to insert a new row, otherwise I want to add to the counter. However, I am struggling with the correct syntax on the update statement. This is what I would like to do:

```
INSERT INTO MyThings SELECT Thing, Counts FROM NewThings
        ON CONFLICT (Thing)
            DO UPDATE SET Count = MyThings.Count + NewThings.Counts;
```

But I only get this to work:

```
INSERT INTO MyThings SELECT Thing, Counts FROM NewThings
        ON CONFLICT (Thing)
            DO UPDATE SET Count = MyThings.Count + 1;
```

How can I correctly add the `counts` value from the `NewThings` table?

Comment: excluded. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#:~:text=must%20be%20provided.-,conflict_action,-conflict_action%20specifies%20an

Comment: BTW: `count` is a bad name for a column. And `count` != `counts`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use EXCLUDED instead of NewThings

```
INSERT INTO MyThings 
SELECT Thing, Counts FROM NewThings
ON CONFLICT (Thing)
DO UPDATE SET Count = Count + EXCLUDED.Count;
```